# LD errors while linking 16-bit real mode code into a Multiboot compliant ELF executable

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, ld, osdev

I'm writing a Multiboot compliant *ELF* executable containing my 32-bit kernel. My primary problem is that I'm receiving a series of linker errors while producing my executable:

> relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'

*Linker Script, Code and Build script below*

I have decided to try implementing VESA VBE graphics in my OS. I found an existing VESA driver in the [OSDev forum](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17230) and I tried to integrate it into my own OS. I tried adding it to my source directory, assembled it with *NASM* and linked it into a final executable with *LD*. The specific errors I received were:

```
vesa.asm:(.text+0x64): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
obj/vesa.o: In function `svga_mode':
vesa.asm:(.text+0x9d): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
vesa.asm:(.text+0xb5): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
obj/vesa.o: In function `done':
vesa.asm:(.text+0xc7): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
```

The lines causing the error (in order) are the following:

```
mov ax,[vid_mode]
mov cx,[vid_mode]
mov bx,[vid_mode]
jmp 0x8:pm1
```

I have also commented the lines with "Linker error"

Here is the file (vesa.asm):

```
BITS    32

global do_vbe

save_idt: dd 0
          dw 0
save_esp: dd 0
vid_mode: dw 0

do_vbe:
cli
mov word [vid_mode],ax
mov [save_esp],esp
sidt [save_idt]
lidt [0x9000] ;; saved on bootup see loader.asm

jmp 0x18:pmode
pmode:
mov ax,0x20
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov fs,ax
mov gs,ax
mov ss,ax
mov eax,cr0
dec eax
mov cr0,eax
jmp 0:realmode1

[bits 16]
realmode1:
xor ax,ax
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov fs,ax
mov gs,ax
mov ss,ax
mov sp,0xf000
sti

;; first zero out the 256 byte memory for the return function from getmodeinfo
cld
;; ax is already zero! I just saved myself a few bytes!!
mov cx,129
mov di,0x5000
rep stosw

mov ax,[vid_mode] ; Linker error 
xor ax,0x13
jnz svga_mode

;; Ok, just a regular mode13
mov ax,0x13
int 0x10
;; we didnt actually get a Vidmode structure in 0x5000, so we 
;; fake it with the stuff the kernel actually uses
mov word [0x5001],0xDD     ; mode attribs, and my favorite cup size
mov word [0x5013],320      ; width
mov word [0x5015],200      ; height
mov byte [0x501a],8        ; bpp
mov byte [0x501c],1        ; memory model type = CGA
mov dword [0x5029],0xa0000 ; screen memory
jmp done

svga_mode:

mov ax,0x4f01 ; Get mode info function
mov cx,[vid_mode] ; Linker error 
or cx,0x4000 ; always try to use linear buffer
mov di,0x5001
int 0x10
mov [0x5000],ah
or ah,ah
jnz done

mov ax,0x4f02 ; Now actually set the mode
mov bx,[vid_mode] ; ; Linker error 
or bx,0x4000
int 0x10

done:
cli
mov eax,cr0
inc eax
mov cr0,eax
jmp 0x8:pm1 ; Linker error

[bits 32]
pm1:
mov eax,0x10
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov fs,ax
mov gs,ax
mov ss,ax
mov dword esp,[save_esp]
lidt [save_idt]
ret
```

Main entry file (entry.asm):

```
extern kmain
extern do_vbe

; Multiboot Header
MBALIGN     equ 1<<0
MEMINFO     equ 1<<1
;VIDINFO        equ 1<<2
FLAGS       equ MBALIGN | MEMINFO; | VIDINFO
MAGIC       equ 0x1BADB002
CHECKSUM    equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

section .text
align 4

dd MAGIC
dd FLAGS
dd CHECKSUM
;dd 0
;dd 0
;dd 0
;dd 0
;dd 0
;dd 0
;dd 800
;dd 600
;dd 32

STACKSIZE equ 0x4000

global entry

entry:


    mov esp, stack+STACKSIZE
    push eax

    push ebx

    call do_vbe

    cli
    call kmain

    cli
    hlt
hang:
    jmp hang

section .bss
align 32
stack:
    resb STACKSIZE
```

My linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(entry)
SECTIONS
 {
   . = 100000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
 }
```

My build script (Note I am using Cygwin):

```
cd src

for i in *.asm
do
    echo Assembling $i
    nasm -f elf32 -o "../obj/${i%.asm}.o" "$i"
done

for i in *.cpp
do
    echo Compiling $i
    i686-elf-g++ -c "$i" -o "../obj/${i%.cpp}.o" -I ../include --freestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=c++14 -Wno-write-strings
done

for i in *.S
do
    echo Compiling $i
    i686-elf-as -c "$i" -o "../obj/${i%.S}.o"
done

for i in *.c
do
    echo Compiling $i
    i686-elf-gcc -c "$i" -o "../obj/${i%.cpp}.o" -I ../include --freestanding
done

cd ..

i686-elf-ld -m elf_i386 -T linkscript.ld -o bin/kernel.sys obj/*.o
```

If it helps here is the directory structure:

```
/src Source Files
/include Include files
/obj Object files
/bin Kernel Executable
```

Comment: Ok i will add the commands i use and try using [dword vid_mode] although this wont fix jmp 0x8:pm1. Also note that i am not using grub i am using syslinux

Comment: ok using 32bit addressing solved the linking problem, but now it triple faults, so now i just have to solve that problem :)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Using `[dword vid_mode]` will solve the linking problem, but will generate a general protection fault when executed because the address of `vid_mode` is beyond the 0xFFFF real-mode segment limit.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't think unreal mode is workable in this case since he's using BIOS calls which will will reset the segment limits to their normal real-mode values.  A better solution would just be to copy the real mode code and `vid_mode` variable to somewhere where real mode can access it normally.

Comment: @RossRidge : I'd agree. I put a note under one of my earlier comments _Usually I place the code that is expected to be used in real mode in lower memory (things are much easier if it is in the first 64kb)_ . .Anything under 1mb would work (<64kb has the least pain). I should ave said code/data. Part of the code shown does seem to manually put some of the data in lower memory, but I didn't go looking at the OSDEV forum linked to find out what they were really trying to do.

Comment: To make a bootable media with syslinux i created a vhd file with diskmgmt.msc , mounted it then used syslinux.exe to make it bootable using syslinux, added the multiboot module and made the boot config boot my kernel

Comment: It's important to realize that a lot of low level code like this is heavily assuming and interdependent on the environment - the person to post the source was nice enough to provide you a good part of these assumptions - and yet you violated many of those assumptions by virtue of using multiboot. Besides the posted answer to correct these assumptions, the lesson to learn is to assess these assumptions in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Reason for the Linker Error

This error you received:

> relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'

is effectively telling you that when the linker attempted to resolve these relocations within the `.text` section that it was unable to do so because the Virtual Memory Addresses (VMA) it computed could not fit in a 16-bit pointer (`_16`).

If you use `-g -Fdwarf` when assembling with *NASM* you can produce more usable output from *OBJDUMP* using a command like `i686-elf-objdump -SDr -Mi8086  vesa.o`.

- `-S` outputs source
- `-D` is for disassembly,
- `-r` shows the relocation information.

The following is the output I get (it differs slightly but the ideas presented here still apply):

```
0000004a <realmode1>:

[bits 16]
realmode1:
...
mov ax,[vid_mode] ; Linker error
  63:   a1 0a 00                mov    ax,ds:0xa
                        64: R_386_16    .text
...
mov cx,[vid_mode] ; Linker error
  9a:   8b 0e 0a 00             mov    cx,WORD PTR ds:0xa
                        9c: R_386_16    .text
...
mov bx,[vid_mode] ; ; Linker error
  b2:   8b 1e 0a 00             mov    bx,WORD PTR ds:0xa
                        b4: R_386_16    .text
...
jmp 0x8:pm1 ; Linker error
  c5:   ea ca 00 08 00          jmp    0x8:0xca
                        c6: R_386_16    .text
```

I have removed the information that wasn't of any consequence for brevity and replaced it with `...` in the output. There is a `[bits 16]` directive that forces all memory addresses to be 16-bit unless overridden. As an example `c6: R_386_16    .text` means there is a relocation at offset (0xc6) that is a 16-bit pointer appearing in the `.text` section. Keep this in mind. Now review the linker script:

```
. = 100000;
.text : { *(.text) }
.data : { *(.data) }
.bss  : { *(.bss)  }
```

The VMA (origin) is 0x100000. This is effectively the origin point for all the code and data in this case. All the addresses generated in the final executable will be over 0xFFFF which is the maximum value that can fit in a 16-bit pointer. This is the reason the linker is complaining.

You can override the default address and operand sizes by specifying *DWORD* before the label name between the brackets `[` and `]`. An absolute 32-bit *FAR JMP* can be encoded by specifying *DWORD* before the operand. These lines:

```
mov ax,[vid_mode]
mov cx,[vid_mode]
mov bx,[vid_mode]
jmp 0x8:pm1
```

Would become:

```
mov ax,[dword vid_mode]
mov cx,[dword vid_mode]
mov bx,[dword vid_mode]
jmp dword 0x8:pm1
```

If you assemble the revised code and use *OBJDUMP* as discussed above you get this output (cut for brevity):

```
mov ax,[dword vid_mode] ; Linker error
  63:   67 a1 0a 00 00 00       addr32 mov ax,ds:0xa
                        65: R_386_32    .text
...
mov cx,[dword vid_mode] ; Linker error
  9d:   67 8b 0d 0a 00 00 00    addr32 mov cx,WORD PTR ds:0xa
                        a0: R_386_32    .text
...
mov bx,[dword vid_mode] ; ; Linker error
  b8:   67 8b 1d 0a 00 00 00    addr32 mov bx,WORD PTR ds:0xa
                        bb: R_386_32    .text
...
jmp dword 0x8:pm1 ; Linker error
  ce:   66 ea d6 00 00 00 08    jmp    0x8:0xd6
  d5:   00
                        d0: R_386_32    .text
```

The instructions now have a `0x66` and `0x67` prefix added to them and the addresses take 4 bytes in the instruction. Each of the relocations are of type `R_386_32` which tells the linker that the addresses to relocate are 32-bits wide.

---

Although the changes in the previous section will eliminate the warnings during linking, when run things may not work as expected (including crashes). On an 80386+ you can generate 16-bit real mode code that uses 32-bit addresses for the data but the CPU has to be put into a mode that allows such access. The mode that allows 32-bit pointers accessed via the *DS* segment with values above 0xFFFF is called [Unreal Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode). [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode) has some code that could be used as a basis for such support. Assuming the PICs haven't been remapped and are in their initial configuration then the usual way to implement on demand Unreal Mode is to replace the 0x0d Interrupt handler with something that does:

1. Query [PIC1](http://wiki.osdev.org/8259_PIC) OCW3 to see if IRQ5 is being serviced or whether there was a General Protection fault. Without PIC remapping #GP fault and IRQ5 point at the same interrupt vector so one has to distinguish between them.
2. If the IRQ5 ISR is set then call the previously saved interrupt handler (chaining). At this point we are all done.
3. If IRQ5 ISR is not set then 0x0d interrupt was called because of a general protection fault. Assume the fault was because of an invalid data access.
4. Switch into protected mode and use a GDT containing a 16-bit data descriptor that has a base of 0 and a limit of 0xffffffff. Set *ES* and *DS* using the corresponding selector.
5. Leave protected mode
6. Return from interrupt handler.

If PIC1 has been remapped so as to not conflict with the x86 exception handling interrupts (int 0x08 to int 0x0f) then steps 1,2,3 no longer apply. [Remapping the PICs](http://wiki.osdev.org/8259_PIC#Protected_Mode) to avoid this conflict is common place in x86 OS design. The code in the question doesn't do any PIC remapping.

This mechanism won't work if you want to ever use the code in a VM8086 task rather than entering real mode.

DOS's HIMEM.SYS did something similar in the 1980s and you can find a discussion about that in this [article](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/himem-sys-unreal-mode-and-loadall/) if you are interested.

**Note** : Although I give a general description of using Unreal Mode, I don't recommend this method. It requires more extensive knowledge of real mode, protected mode, interrupt handling.

---

### More Preferred Solution

Rather than using 32-bit data pointers greater than 0xFFFF, and ensuring that the processor is in unreal mode there is a solution that may be easier to understand. One such solution is to copy the real mode code and data from where the Multiboot loader physically loaded into RAM above 0x100000 to the first 64KB of memory memory just above the real mode interrupt vector table (IVT). This allows you to continue using 16-bit pointers because the first 64KB of memory is addressable with a 16-bit pointer (0x0000 to 0xFFFF). The 32-bit code will still be able to access the real mode data if needed.

To do this you will have to create a more complex GNU *LD* [linker script](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html) (`link.ld`) that uses a Virtual Memory Address (origin point) in lower memory. Address 0x01000 is a good choice. The Multiboot header will still have to be present at the beginning of the *ELF* executable.

One problem that has to be overcome is that the Multiboot loader will read the code and data into memory above 0x100000. One has to manually copy the 16-bit real mode code and data to address 0x01000 before the real mode code can be used. The linker script can help generate symbols to compute the start and end addresses for such a copy.

See the code in the last section for a linker script `link.ld` that does just that, and a `kernel.c` file that does the copy.

With properly adjusted VESA code what you are trying to do should work.

---

### Problems with VESA Code You Found

- The [VESA code](http://forum.osdev.org/download/file.php?id=698&sid=89628fa36a9e08e1df593930856e1cc6) relies on hard coded addresses
- Was not designed with Multiboot in mind as it was assumed the kernel would be manually loaded into memory (<64KB) at a specific place and that certain addresses already contained specific data before being called.
- The code doesn't follow the [*CDECL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) calling convention thus it isn't callable from *C* code directly.
- There is a bug that placed 32-bit code under a `[bits 16]` directive.
- The code doesn't show the *GDT* table that was needed but it can be inferred from the code that there needed to be *at least* 5 descriptors in a *GDT* in a specific order.

  1. Null Descriptor
  2. 32-bit Code Segment (Base 0, Limit 0xffffffff). Selector 0x08
  3. 32-bit Data Segment (Base 0, Limit 0xffffffff). Selector 0x10
  4. 16-bit Code Segment (Base 0, Limit at least 0xffff). Selector 0x18
  5. 16-bit Data Segment (Base 0, Limit at least 0xffff). Selector 0x20

The author had these comments:

> On boot up save the real mode IDT at a known place (mine was at 0x9000) using the sidt instruction, and dont overwrite address 0-0x500 in memory. It also assumes that you are using 8 and 16 as segment registers for code and data in PMode. It stores the result of function 4f01 at 0x5000, and automatically sets bit 13 (use framebuffer)

---

### A Complete Example

The following code is a complete implementation of what has been suggested above. Use a linker script and generate real mode code and data and place it starting at 0x1000. The code uses *C* to set up a proper *GDT* with 32 and 16-bit Code and Data segments, copies the real mode code from above 0x100000 down to 0x1000. It also fixes the other issues previously identified in the VESA driver code. To test it switches in to video mode 0x13 (320x200x256) and paints part of the VGA color palette to the display 32 bits at a time.

`link.ld`:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386");
ENTRY(mbentry);

/* Multiboot spec uses 0x00100000 as a base */
PHYS_BASE = 0x00100000;
REAL_BASE = 0x00001000;

SECTIONS
{
    . = PHYS_BASE;

    /* Place the multiboot record first */
    .multiboot : {
        *(.multiboot);
    }

    /* This is the tricky part. The LMA (load memory address) is the
     * memory location the code/data is read into memory by the
     * multiboot loader. The LMA is after the colon. We want to tell
     * the linker that the code/data in this section was loaded into
     * RAM in the memory area above 0x100000. On the other hand the
     * VMA (virtual memory address) specified before the colon acts
     * like an ORG directive. The VMA tells the linker to resolve all
     * subsequent code starting relative to the specified VMA. The
     * VMA in this case is REAL_BASE which we defined as 0x1000.
     * 0x1000 is 4KB page aligned (useful if you ever use paging) and
     * resides above the end of the interrupt table and the
     * BIOS Data Area (BDA)
     */

    __physreal_diff = . - REAL_BASE;
    .realmode REAL_BASE : AT(ADDR(.realmode) + __physreal_diff) {
        /* The __realmode* values can be used by code to copy
         * the code/data from where it was placed in RAM by the
         * multiboot loader into lower memory at REAL_BASE
         *
         * . (period) is the current VMA */
        __realmode_vma_start = .;

        /* LOADADDR is the LMA of the specified section */
        __realmode_lma_start = LOADADDR(.realmode);
        *(.text.realmode);
        *(.data.realmode);
    }
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __realmode_vma_end = .;
    __realmode_secsize   = ((__realmode_vma_end)-(__realmode_vma_start));
    __realmode_secsize_l = __realmode_secsize>>2;
    __realmode_lma_end   = __realmode_vma_start + __physreal_diff + __realmode_secsize;

    /* . (period) is the current VMA. We set it to the value that would
     * have been generated had we not changed the VMA in the previous
     * section. The .text section also specified the LMA = VMA with
     * AT(ADDR(.text))
     */
    . += __physreal_diff;
    .text ALIGN(4K): AT(ADDR(.text)) {
        *(.text);
    }

    /* From this point the linker script is typical */
    .data ALIGN(4K) : {
        *(.data);
    }

    .data ALIGN(4K) : {
        *(.rodata);
    }

    /* We want to avoid this section being placed in low memory */
    .eh_frame : {
        *(.eh_frame*);
    }

    .bss ALIGN(4K): {
        *(COMMON);
        *(.bss)
    }

    /* The .note.gnu.build-id section will usually be placed at the beginning
     * of the ELF object. We discard it (if it is present) so that the
     * multiboot header is placed as early as possible in the file. The
     * multiboot header must appear in the first 8K and be on a 4 byte
     * aligned offset per the multiboot spec.
     */
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.note.gnu.build-id);
        *(.comment);
    }
}
```

`gdt.inc` :

```
CODE32SEL equ 0x08
DATA32SEL equ 0x10
CODE16SEL equ 0x18
DATA16SEL equ 0x20
```

`vesadrv.asm` :

```
; Video driver code - switches the CPU back into real mode
; Then executes an int 0x10 instruction

%include "gdt.inc"

global do_vbe

bits 16
section .data.realmode
save_idt: dw 0
          dd 0
save_esp: dd 0
vid_mode: dw 0
real_ivt: dw (256 * 4) - 1      ; Realmode IVT has 256 CS:IP pairs
          dd 0                  ; Realmode IVT physical address at address 0x00000

align 4
mode_info:TIMES 129 dw 0        ; Buffer to store mode info from Int 10h/ax=4f01h
                                ; Plus additional bytes for the return status byte
                                ; at beginning of buffer

bits 32
section .text
do_vbe:
    mov ax, [esp+4]             ; Retrieve videomode passed on stack
    pushad                      ; Save all the registers
    pushfd                      ; Save the flags (including Interrupt flag)
    cli
    mov word [vid_mode],ax
    mov [save_esp],esp
    sidt [save_idt]
    lidt [real_ivt]             ; We use a real ivt that points to the
                                ; physical address 0x00000 at the bottom of
                                ; memory. The IVT in real mode is 256*4 bytes
                                ; and runs from physical address 0x00000 to
                                ; 0x00400
    jmp CODE16SEL:pmode16

bits 16
section .text.realmode
pmode16:
    mov ax,DATA16SEL
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov fs,ax
    mov gs,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov eax,cr0
    dec eax
    mov cr0,eax
    jmp 0:realmode1

realmode1:
    ; Sets real mode stack to grow down from 0x1000:0xFFFF
    mov ax,0x1000
    mov ss,ax
    xor sp,sp

    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov fs,ax
    mov gs,ax

    ; first zero out the 258 byte memory for the return function from getmodeinfo
    cld
    mov cx,(258/2)              ; 128 words + 1 word for the status return byte
    mov di,mode_info
    rep stosw

    mov ax,[vid_mode]
    xor ax,0x13
    jnz svga_mode

    ; Just a regular mode13
    mov ax,0x13
    int 0x10

    ; Fake a video mode structure with the stuff the kernel actually uses
    mov di, mode_info
    mov word [di+0x01],0xDD     ; mode attribs
    mov word [di+0x13],320      ; width
    mov word [di+0x15],200      ; height
    mov byte [di+0x1a],8        ; bpp
    mov byte [di+0x1c],1        ; memory model type = CGA
    mov dword [di+0x29],0xa0000 ; screen memory
    jmp done

svga_mode:
    mov ax,0x4f01               ; Get mode info function
    mov cx,[vid_mode]
    or cx,0x4000                ; always try to use linear buffer
    mov di,mode_info+0x01
    int 0x10
    mov [mode_info],ah
    or ah,ah
    jnz done

    mov ax,0x4f02               ; Now actually set the mode
    mov bx,[vid_mode]
    or bx,0x4000
    int 0x10

done:
    cli
    mov eax,cr0
    inc eax
    mov cr0,eax
    jmp dword CODE32SEL:pm1     ; To FAR JMP to address > 0xFFFF we need
                                ; to specify DWORD to allow a 32-bit address
                                ; in the offset portion. When this JMP is
                                ; complete CS will be CODE32SEL and processor
                                ; will be in 32-bit protected mode

bits 32
section .text
pm1:
    mov eax,DATA32SEL
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov fs,ax
    mov gs,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov dword esp,[save_esp]
    lidt [save_idt]
    popfd                       ; Restore flags (including Interrupt flag)
    popad                       ; Restore registers

    mov eax, mode_info          ; Return pointer to mode_info structure
    ret
```

`vesadrv.h` :

```
#ifndef VESADRV_H
#define VESADRV_H

#include <stdint.h>

extern struct mode_info_t * do_vbe (const uint8_t video_mode);

struct mode_info_t {
    uint8_t status; /* Return value from Int 10/ax=4f01 */

    /* Rest of structure from OSDev Wiki
       http://wiki.osdev.org/VESA_Video_Modes#VESA_Functions
    */
    uint16_t attributes;
    uint8_t winA,winB;
    uint16_t granularity;
    uint16_t winsize;
    uint16_t segmentA, segmentB;

    /* Real mode FAR Pointer.  Physical address
     * computed as (segment<<4)+offset
     */
    uint16_t realFctPtr_offset; /* FAR Pointer offset */
    uint16_t realFctPtr_segment;/* FAR Pointer segment */

    uint16_t pitch; /* bytes per scanline */

    uint16_t Xres, Yres;
    uint8_t Wchar, Ychar, planes, bpp, banks;
    uint8_t memory_model, bank_size, image_pages;
    uint8_t reserved0;

    uint8_t red_mask, red_position;
    uint8_t green_mask, green_position;
    uint8_t blue_mask, blue_position;
    uint8_t rsv_mask, rsv_position;
    uint8_t directcolor_attributes;

    volatile void * physbase;  /* LFB (Linear Framebuffer) address */
    uint32_t reserved1;
    uint16_t reserved2;
} __attribute__((packed));

#endif
```

`gdt.h` :

```
#ifndef GDT_H
#define GDT_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
        unsigned short limit_low;
        unsigned short base_low;
        unsigned char base_middle;
        unsigned char access;
        unsigned char flags;
        unsigned char base_high;
} __attribute__((packed)) gdt_desc_t;

typedef struct {
    uint16_t limit;
    gdt_desc_t *gdt;
} __attribute__((packed)) gdtr_t;

extern void gdt_set_gate(gdt_desc_t gdt[], const int num, const uint32_t base,
                         const uint32_t limit, const uint8_t access,
                         const uint8_t flags);

static inline void gdt_load(gdtr_t * const gdtr, const uint16_t codesel,
                            const uint16_t datasel, const bool flush)
{    
    /* load the GDT register */
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("lgdt %[gdtr]"
                          :
                          : [gdtr]"m"(*gdtr),
                          /* Dummy constraint to ensure what gdtr->gdt points at is fully
                           * realized into memory before we issue LGDT instruction */
                            "m"(*(const gdt_desc_t (*)[]) gdtr->gdt));

    /* This flushes the selector registers to ensure the new
     * descriptors are used. */
    if (flush) {
        /* The indirect absolute jump is because we can't
         * assume that codesel is an immediate value
         * as it may be passed in a register. We build a
         * far pointer in memory and indirectly jump through
         * that pointer. This explicitly sets CS selector */
        __asm__  __volatile__ (
                 "pushl %[codesel]\n\t"
                 "pushl $1f\n\t"
                 "ljmpl *(%%esp)\n"
                 "1:\n\t"
                 "add $8, %%esp\n\t"
                 "mov %[datasel], %%ds\n\t"
                 "mov %[datasel], %%es\n\t"
                 "mov %[datasel], %%ss\n\t"
                 "mov %[datasel], %%fs\n\t"
                 "mov %[datasel], %%gs"
                 : /* No outputs */
                 : [datasel]"r"(datasel),
                   [codesel]"g"((uint32_t)codesel));
    }
    return;
}
#endif
```

`gdt.c` :

```
#include "gdt.h"

/* Setup a descriptor in the Global Descriptor Table */
void gdt_set_gate(gdt_desc_t gdt[], const int num, const uint32_t base,
                  const uint32_t limit, const uint8_t access,
                  const uint8_t flags)
{
        /* Setup the descriptor base access */
        gdt[num].base_low = (base & 0xFFFF);
        gdt[num].base_middle = (base >> 16) & 0xFF;
        gdt[num].base_high = (base >> 24) & 0xFF;

        /* Setup the descriptor limits */
        gdt[num].limit_low = (limit & 0xFFFF);
        gdt[num].flags = ((limit >> 16) & 0x0F);

        /* Finally, set up the flags and access byte */
        gdt[num].flags |= (flags << 4);
        gdt[num].access = access;
}
```

`multiboot.asm` :

```
%include "gdt.inc"

STACKSIZE equ 0x4000

bits 32
global mbentry

extern kmain

; Multiboot Header
section .multiboot
MBALIGN     equ 1<<0
MEMINFO     equ 1<<1
VIDINFO     equ 0<<2
FLAGS       equ MBALIGN | MEMINFO | VIDINFO
MAGIC       equ 0x1BADB002
CHECKSUM    equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

mb_hdr:
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

section .text
mbentry:
    cli
    cld
    mov esp, stack_top

    ; EAX = magic number. Should be 0x2badb002
    ; EBX = pointer to multiboot_info
    ; Pass as parameters right to left
    push eax
    push ebx
    call kmain

    ; Infinite loop to end program
    cli
endloop:
    hlt
    jmp endloop

section .bss
align 32
stack:
    resb STACKSIZE
stack_top:
```

`kernel.c` :

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "vesadrv.h"
#include "gdt.h"

#define CODE32SEL 0x08
#define DATA32SEL 0x10
#define CODE16SEL 0x18
#define DATA16SEL 0x20
#define NUM_GDT_ENTRIES 5

/* You can get this structure from GRUB's multiboot.h if needed
 * https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/html_node/multiboot_002eh.html
 */
struct multiboot_info;

/* Values made available by the linker script */
extern void *__realmode_lma_start;
extern void *__realmode_lma_end;
extern void *__realmode_vma_start;

/* Pointer to graphics memory.Mark as volatile since
 * video memory is memory mapped IO. Certain optimization
 * should not be performed. */
volatile uint32_t * video_gfx_ptr;

/* GDT descriptor table */
gdt_desc_t gdt[NUM_GDT_ENTRIES];

/* Copy the code and data in the realmode section down into the lower
 * 64kb of memory @ 0x00001000. */
static void realmode_setup (void)
{
    /* Each of these __realmode* values is generated by the linker script */
    uint32_t *src_addr = (uint32_t *)&__realmode_lma_start;
    uint32_t *dst_addr = (uint32_t *)&__realmode_vma_start;
    uint32_t *src_end  = (uint32_t *)&__realmode_lma_end;

    /* Copy a DWORD at a time from source to destination */
    while (src_addr < src_end)
        *dst_addr++ = *src_addr++;
}

void gdt_setup (gdt_desc_t gdt[], const int numdesc)
{
    gdtr_t gdtr = { sizeof(gdt_desc_t)*numdesc-1, gdt };

    /* Null descriptor */
    gdt_set_gate(gdt, 0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00, 0x0);
    /* 32-bit Code descriptor, flat 4gb */
    gdt_set_gate(gdt, 1, 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0x9A, 0xC);
    /* 32-bit Data descriptor, flat 4gb */
    gdt_set_gate(gdt, 2, 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0x92, 0xC);
    /* 16-bit Code descriptor, limit 0xffff bytes */
    gdt_set_gate(gdt, 3, 0x00000000, 0x0000ffff, 0x9A, 0x0);
    /* 16-bit Data descriptor, limit 0xffffffff bytes */
    gdt_set_gate(gdt, 4, 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0x92, 0x8);

    /* Load global decriptor table, and flush the selectors */
    gdt_load(&gdtr, CODE32SEL, DATA32SEL, true);
}

int kmain(struct multiboot_info *mb_info, const uint32_t magicnum)
{
    struct mode_info_t *pMI;
    uint32_t pixel_colors = 0;

    /* Quiet compiler about unused variables */
    (void) mb_info;
    (void) magicnum;

    /* Setup the GDT */
    gdt_setup(gdt, NUM_GDT_ENTRIES);

    /* Setup real mode code and data */
    realmode_setup();

    /* Switch to video mode 0x13 (320x200x256)
     * The physical address of the mode 13 video memory is
     * 0xa0000 */
    pMI = do_vbe(0x13);
    video_gfx_ptr = pMI->physbase;

    /* Display part of the VGA palette as a test pattern */
    for (int pixelpos = 0; pixelpos < (320*200); pixelpos++) {
        if ((pixel_colors & 0xff) == (320/4))
            pixel_colors = 0;
        pixel_colors += 0x01010101;
        video_gfx_ptr[pixelpos] = pixel_colors;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A simple set of commands to assemble/compile/link the code above into an *ELF* executable called `multiboot.elf`:

```
nasm -f elf32 -g -F dwarf -o multiboot.o multiboot.asm
nasm -f elf32 -g -F dwarf -o vesadrv.o vesadrv.asm
i686-elf-gcc -std=c99 -g -m32 -O3 -c -fno-exceptions -nostdlib -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -o kernel.o kernel.c
i686-elf-gcc -std=c99 -g -m32 -O3 -c -fno-exceptions -nostdlib -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o gdt.o gdt.c -lgcc
i686-elf-gcc -m32 -Tlink.ld -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o multiboot.elf multiboot.o kernel.o gdt.o vesadrv.o -lgcc
```

---

You can find a copy of the code above on [my site](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/41563879/). When I run the kernel in *QEMU* this is what I see:

[image]