# How to shutdown from protected mode using APM?

Tags: c++, assembly, kernel, power-management

My kernel boots using GRUB so it starts in protected mode and A20 line is already unlocked. Then it reroute device irqs and load its own. Now I want to shutdown device. It can be done with APM but APM can be only enabled from real mode so I wrote the code that switches into real mode and then connects to APM, set its version to 1.1/1.2, enable its for all devices and turn off all devices:

```
asm volatile("cli\n"
           "mov eax, cr0\n"
           "and al, not 1\n"
           "mov cr0, eax\n"
           "sti");

  asm volatile("mov ah, 0x53\n"
           "mov al, 0x01\n"
           "xor bx, bx\n"
           "int 0x15");

  asm volatile("mov ah, 0x53\n"
           "mov al, 0x0e\n"
           "mov bx, 0x0000\n"
           "mov ch, 0x01\n"
           "int 0x15");

  asm volatile("mov ah, 0x53\n"
           "mov al, 0x08\n"
           "mov bx, 0x0001\n"
           "mov cx, 0x0001\n"
           "int 0x15");

  asm volatile("mov ah, 0x53\n"
           "mov al, 0x07\n"
           "mov bx, 0x0001\n"
           "mov cx, 0x3\n"
           "int 0x15");
```

Also after running this code computer reboots and while using QEMU I receive booting error (invalid "magic number") and while using real machine it just reboots.

Comment: Did you reset the real mode interrupts with LIDT?

Comment: It is far more complex. There is a complete Multiboot example in this answer that switches into real mode to do some vbe calls (and then returns back to protected mode). https://stackoverflow.com/a/41731180/3857942  . Of course you don't need to worry about all the code that exists to restore the state to return to protected mode as you are shutting down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU style inline assembly requires all registers that are not in the output or clobber list to be preserved, likewise changing to real mode will break code produced by the compiler. Fix this my using a single asm statement, or use a separate assembly file.

You try to enter 32-bit real mode, you need switch to 16-bit mode before switching to real mode.

You need to set `CS` to a suitable value for real mode using a far jump, otherwise the first return from an interrupt will go to the wrong address.

You can find an example of switching from 32-bit protected mode to real mode in the GRUB source.

Comment: How to far jump to 0x15 interrupt?

Comment: No, far jump to your own code, twice. First to enter 16-bit mode (using a segment descriptor for a 16-bit segment), then after leaving protected mode.

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin : of course in this case no need to come back out of protected mode since the machine is being shutdown.